# How to add the text from speech_to_text to a tag created using TextFieldTags widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, textfield, speech-to-text

I have the following code for making tags in my flutter application. I wish to add the functionality of speech_to_text where a user speaks and the text shows up in the field. How to do that?
I am able to add the functionaloty of speech to text seperately in a plain text field but cannot integrate it with tags. This is my problem.

```
              TextFieldTags(
                textfieldTagsController: _controllerD,
                textSeparators: const [','],
                letterCase: LetterCase.normal,
                validator: (String tag) {
                  diagnosis.add(tag);
                },
                inputfieldBuilder:
                    (context, tec, focus, error, onChanged, onSubmitted) {
                  return ((context, sc, tags, onTagDelete) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: tec,
                        focusNode: focus,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          isDense: true,
                          border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.blueGrey,
                              width: 3.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.blueGrey,
                              width: 3.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          hintText: _controllerD.hasTags ? '' : "Enter patient's diagnosis...",
                          errorText: error,
                          prefixIconConstraints:
                          BoxConstraints(maxWidth: _distanceToField * 0.74),
                          prefixIcon: tags.isNotEmpty
                              ? SingleChildScrollView(
                            controller: sc,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: Row(
                                children: tags.map((String tag) {
                                  return Container(
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                        Radius.circular(10.0),
                                      ),
                                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                    ),
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 5.0),
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        InkWell(
                                          child: Text(
                                            '$tag',
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                          onTap: () {
                                            print("$tag selected");
                                          },
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(width: 4.0),
                                        InkWell(
                                          child: const Icon(
                                            Icons.cancel,
                                            size: 14.0,
                                            color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                255, 233, 233, 233),
                                          ),
                                          onTap: () {
                                            onTagDelete(tag);
                                            diagnosis.remove(tag);
                                          },
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }).toList()),
                          )
                              : null,
                        ),
                        onChanged: onChanged,
                        onSubmitted: (tag){
                          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus);
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  });
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package called `speech_to_text` ([link](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text)). This package allows you to convert speech to text as you have mentioned. It also comes with methods for starting, stopping, and continuously listening to the voice and converting it to text.

Here's an example code(source on pub.dev):

```js
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  SpeechToText _speechToText = SpeechToText();
  bool _speechEnabled = false;
  String _lastWords = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initSpeech();
  }

  /// This has to happen only once per app
  void _initSpeech() async {
    _speechEnabled = await _speechToText.initialize();
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// Each time to start a speech recognition session
  void _startListening() async {
    await _speechToText.listen(onResult: _onSpeechResult);
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// Manually stop the active speech recognition session
  /// Note that there are also timeouts that each platform enforces
  /// and the SpeechToText plugin supports setting timeouts on the
  /// listen method.
  void _stopListening() async {
    await _speechToText.stop();
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// This is the callback that the SpeechToText plugin calls when
  /// the platform returns recognized words.
  void _onSpeechResult(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    setState(() {
      _lastWords = result.recognizedWords;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Speech Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Text(
                'Recognized words:',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Text(
                  // If listening is active show the recognized words
                  _speechToText.isListening
                      ? '$_lastWords'
                      // If listening isn't active but could be tell the user
                      // how to start it, otherwise indicate that speech
                      // recognition is not yet ready or not supported on
                      // the target device
                      : _speechEnabled
                          ? 'Tap the microphone to start listening...'
                          : 'Speech not available',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed:
            // If not yet listening for speech start, otherwise stop
            _speechToText.isNotListening ? _startListening : _stopListening,
        tooltip: 'Listen',
        child: Icon(_speechToText.isNotListening ? Icons.mic_off : Icons.mic),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code doesn't describe to put values into the `TextField`, but you can easily achieve it by following way:

1. You can use this package for listening and converting the data to text format.
2. You can set your `TextEditingController` to the text value by simply assigning it to it.

example: `textController.text = value` // where value is your speech to text data and textController is your `TextEditingController`.